# unable to change href attribute to a tag using each func and reading data from table

Tags: jquery

this is driving me nuts,i am trying to change the href attribute which are read by a table displayed in html.

here is my html code

```
        <div id="packgeImages">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="title" rel="shadowbox">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="title" rel="shadowbox">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="title" rel="shadowbox">Link3</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="title" rel="shadowbox">Link4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is the JQuery Code to change that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var hrefText = $('[rel=shadowbox]').attr('href');//Get the Value of href from Li
        $('#fullImgGridView tr').each(function (i) {
            if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skips first row
            var bigSizeImagePath = this.cells[0].innerHTML; //Read Value
            alert(bigSizeImagePath); //Alert Value, Checked/Works Fine
            $('[rel=shadowbox]').attr("href", bigSizeImagePath); //Sets the Paths using last record of table//
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now it works but the **problem is that it sets the href atrribute to the last record of the table. And not one by One.**
Please help me with this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your filter selects all your `<li>` tags

```
$('[rel=shadowbox]').attr("href", bigSizeImagePath);
```

Try to select the matching index :

```
$('[rel=shadowbox]').eq(this.rowIndex - 1).attr("href", bigSizeImagePath);
```

(this.rowIndex - 1) is because you skip the first line

Comment: YEY! IT WORKED.. Wohooo! THanks man. thanks for all the Support. So now eq means going through all rows and why we skipped first line?can you explain a bit.. thanks

Comment: eq selector get the nth element of the current set `$('[rel=shadowbox]')`. -1 is because in your script you skip the first row : `if (!this.rowIndex) return;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in

```
$('[rel=shadowbox]').attr("href", bigSizeImagePath);
```

Which sets the `href` for *all* objects matching `[rel=shadowbox]`. You only want to set this one:

```
$(this).find('a').attr("href", bigSizeImagePath);
```

Your HTML isn't clear but if you actually have a `TABLE` and a `UL` and you're trying to update the UL from the TABLE, try this:

```
$('#packgeImages li:eq('+(this.rowIndex-1)+') a[rel=shadowbox]').attr("href", bigSizeImagePath);
```

...which uses `rowIndex` to select the corresponding numbered `LI` out of the `<div id="packgeImages">` and set the href on that.

Comment: In what way is that not working? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Your javascript is not consistent with your HTML so I had to guess - your javascript loops over `TR` tags but your HTML is based on `LI` tags.

Comment: It does not set the links, and the main problem that i encountered was that it only sets the link by reading the last record from table and not row wise.

Comment: Right. Well I explained why that occurs with your code - `$('[rel=shadowbox]')` will set the href for all items with `rel=shadowbox`. My version will only set the href for all `<a>` children of `this`, which, given your example HTML is the right thing. However your example HTML doesn't match your example JS so I'm not sure what you really have.

Comment: Oh, I have another idea what you may be asking - does your source have *both* a `TABLE` and a list `UL` and you want to set the corresponding item in the `UL` from the corresponding row in the `TABLE`?

Comment: you see my friend, when i alert the path like this  alert(bigSizeImagePath);  it works fine and displays 4 path addresses from table. So we are using each function why don't it just one by one add those paths to the href attribute?

Comment: because `$('[rel=shadowbox]')` selects *all* items on the page with a rel of shadowbox, and the `attr` command then updates them all.

Comment: edited my answer based on my new guess about what your question is asking.